# How facebook notify wall updates to fans?

Tags: sql-server, facebook, database-design

I working on social media app and I want users to have option to be notified when page create new post (as in facebook). First, I create a `Notification` table that contain :

```
Id(PK)
UserId
PageId
PostId
ReadBit
Date
```

But this doesn't make sense. If page have 1000 or even 500 interested fans, it doesn't not logically to create 1000 or 500 record for every interested fan. Is there another method to do that ?

Comment: Why doesn't it logically make sense?.

Comment: The point is that the number of fans may be hug. It may be 5000 or even 10000. This mean that whenever one post is created there will be 10000 record. What if fans increased to 100000 ? is this sensible ?

Comment: Facebook did that back in 2011. I'm not sure how much has changed since then, but they were probably bigger at that point than your app is likely to ever be https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/live-commenting-behind-the-scenes/496077348919

Comment: Your table should be as narrow as possible. I wouldn't bother with `PageID`, or `Date`. Just `ID, UserID, PostID, ReadBit`

Comment: Do you want to keep track of whether each fan has seen the notification or not?   If so, then yes, you have to have a row for every fan, no matter how many.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of information you are talking about: Pages and posts.

When a user opts in for a page, this should be persistent, so you'll need a database entry representing this. The standard way to go is to have one record per user and per page she subscribed to:

```
Subscription(id, user_id, page_id)
```

Depending on the exact requirements, there might exist simpler solutions. E.g., if the pages are about topics, and the user doesn't subscribe a page but a topic (like there are 50 pages about cars, and 70 about computers), it would be sufficient to store a subscription per user and topic. But your text doesn't indicate this.

The second question is how to track the notification process when a post has been made to a page. Strictly speaking, you don't need a database record for each such notification. When a page has changed, look up all subscribers using the Subscription table, and in a loop on them generate the notifications.

Only in case that you need some additional persistent information about each such notification you will need a record per notification, i.e.

```
Notification(id, subscription_id, ...)
```

This might be the case if you need to store the timestamp when the notification was sent, or if you have some status information for a notification process, e.g. whether the user has reacted on the notification.